# Create Excel XLS from batch apex via Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, batch, scheduled-apex, excel

I have a scheduled batch apex that currently creates a .CSV document and attaches it to an email, but I have to change it, so instead of a .CSV file, I get a formatted XLS Excel document.

Now, after some investigation, I can see that to achieve an Excel document, I can use a Visualforce page, where I can format my table, however, I'm not able to simply run a query on the object (since there are quite a few), so I have to run a BATCH apex job.

I know that batch apexes are asynchronous, and they don't return anything, however, would it be possible, that in the batch apex's **FINISH** method, I would be able to build up a Visualforce Excel page with my data?

**SECOND IDEA**

Could I do it the following way: use the already working .CSV export, by loading it into a Visualforce page, and then exporting it again as a formatted Excel document?

Comment: How many is "quite a few"? You can't get back to a Visualforce context from Batch Apex *per se*, although there are ways you can monitor the asynchronous job and retrieve its results.

Comment: Well, the requirement is to create a report on all the non-closed leads and the closed ones in the last 7 days. Plus, I would be needing the Lead History objects for them too, which would raise the amount of SELECT operations sent to the server. PS, I added a second idea to my original post, that uses the already working CSV export

Comment: Honestly, I'd recommend JavaScript if you have a super-heavy task like this. You'll get much better performance and won't have to worry about Apex limits.

Comment: @sfdcfox what do you mean by JavaScript? How can I automate that?

Comment: @Laureant Without knowing what limits you're running in to, I'm not sure how to help you. If you need something that requires a batch, you might run in to CPU limits in the finish method, or heap limits, etc. I'm not sure how we're going to help you without knowing what your core problem is.

Comment: @sfdcfox well, the current .csv exports end up at 300-500 rows. The table has 16 columns. So it's not like it's a LOT of data that gets exported.

Comment: @Laureant Maybe just do it in pure Apex then? I don't think batchable is necessary unless you're talking > 50,000 rows.

Comment: @sfdcfox yes, but as I mentioned above, I will have to first get the leads, and then also query their lead histories (so I can see when the changes from one status to the other happened). Currently i'm doing it in a 2 step query process (first I query the leads, and then I iterate through them, and query each leads history) and I'm not sure if I can combine it in ONE query, that would return all rows at once. Do you think that combining these 2 queries could be possible? I have been searching for similar cases, but I haven't found anything helpful. This is the reason that I use batchable.

Comment: Yes, you can do a subquery, such as `select id, (select oldvalue,newvalue,field from histories) from lead`. As long as you have less than 50,000 rows to go through, you should be fine.